# Split field a string and compare each value with string linq c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable

I'm trying to search in DataTable with three string columns[start_date, end_date, expected_visits] using LINQ, but the third column has many lines as shown

[image: date_columns]

So I split the third one with `\n` but I want to loop over date to compare it with text of txtSearchYear and return the result as DataTable, When I tried to use ForEach as shown in my code, An error appeared with me says `A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local` here is my code ...

```
var tblResult =
    tbl
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x =>
            x.Field<string>("start_date").Substring(0, 4).Equals(txtSearchYear.Text.Trim())
            || x.Field<string>("end_date").Substring(0, 4).Equals(txtSearchYear.Text.Trim())
            || x.Field<string>("expected_visits").Split('\n').ToList().ForEach((e) =>
            {
                e.Substring(0, 4).Equals(txtSearchYear.Text.Trim())
            }));

if (tblResult.Any())
{
    GetData(tblResult.CopyToDataTable());
}
else
{
    DGVData.Rows.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you not just change the `e` in the `ForEach` to a different name? What is it about the error that you're not understanding?

Comment: I looked a little deeper and you have invalid code. What are you using `ForEach`? It's just wrong. You should split over `Environment.NewLine` and then use `.Any` to check if any line matches your search text.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you very much, When I used `.Any` the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I would directly compare the year and use the year (int) in lambda and trying to handle the dates as List or Array of Dates instead of comparing substrings, e.g.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

      int year = -1; 
      if (!Int32.TryParse(txtSearchYear.Text.Trim(), out year) || year < 1900)
      {
        throw new InvalidProgramException($"Year {year} isn't valid for us.");
      }
      
      List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
      dates.Add(now);
      dates.Add(now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 10, 10)));
      dates.Add(now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 20, 20)));
      /* ... */

      var myList = dates.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Year == year).ToList();
      Action<DateTime> action = new Action<DateTime>(MyDelegateAction);
      myList.ForEach(e => MyDelegateAction(e));

    }

    private static void MyDelegateAction(DateTime date) { /* do somewhat */; }
```

kind regards, heinrich.